# VB.NET Name 'vbPixels' is not declared and Name 'vbTwips' is not declared

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, vb6, upgrade, vb6-migration

I have some code that I converted in from VB6 to .NET, I get the error Name 'vbPixels' is not declared and Name 'vbTwips' is not declared. This worked fine in VB6.

Here is the code:

```
.Width = o.ScaleX(x, vbPixels, vbTwips)
```

Is there a way in .NET to do the same thing that was done in VB6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not adding vbPixels and vbTwips to VB.NET was **intentional**.  It forces you to deal with the fact that locations and sizes are no longer expressed in *twips*, only pixels.  You *must* convert your code likewise.

Which ought to be simple here since ".Width" already uses pixels as a unit. Thus:

```
  .Width = x
```

Comment: Wow.. That was very informative. That did remove the error. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the VB Power Pack (Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll), [which contains these constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.scalemodeconstants_fields.aspx):

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6

.Width = o.ScaleX(x, ScaleModeConstants.vbPixels, ScaleModeConstants.vbTwips)
```

Comment: I think your answer will work, I just need to tweak it. I added the imports at the top of my file and I got this warning: Warning 14 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing.Compatibility.VB6' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member.

Comment: Then intellisense wants me to change the imports to: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6